# Kaluza-Klein reducing the Chern-Simons term in 11D supergravity

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, supergravity, kaluza-klein

In 11D supergravity we have the Chern-Simons term of the 3-form field $C$
\begin{equation}
\int C \land d C \land d C
\end{equation}
I want to consider this on a spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{1,6}\times S$ where $S$ is a resolution of an $A_n$ singularity. Then $H_2(S)=\mathbb{R}^n$, and I decompose the 3-form as
\begin{equation}
C = \sum_i^n \omega_i \land A_i
\end{equation}
where $\omega_i$ form a basis of the harmonic 2-forms on $S$ and $A_i$ are 1-forms on $\mathbb{R}^{1,6}$. Now plugging this into the Chern-Simons term I get
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{1,6}} \int_S \sum_{ijk}^n \omega_i \land A_i \land\omega_j \land dA_j \land\omega_k \land dA_k \overset{?}{=} \sum_{ijk}^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^{1,6}} \int_S \omega_i \land\omega_j\land\omega_k  \land A_i \land dA_j \land dA_k 
\end{equation}
at which point I'm not sure how to integrate over $S$, especially given that $\omega_i \land\omega_j\land\omega_k$ is a 6-form in a 4-dimensional space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you only use the two-forms of $S$ and one-forms on $\mathbb{R}^{1,6}$? In general $$\Omega^n(X\times Y)=\bigoplus_{p+q=n}\Omega^p(X)\otimes\Omega^q(Y).$$

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə you're right. In the expansion I've ignored other terms. The terms I wrote are of interest because of the $\operatorname{U}(1)$ gauge field term arising when reducing to 7D, although I don't know how to do this. I'm not sure how other terms are dealt with, I'm new to this.

Comment: I've seen in the paper [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9506150.pdf)_Papadopoulos et al_ that we can just write the term $\int_S \omega_i \land \omega_j \land \omega_k = m_{ijk}$, but how can a 6-form be defined in a 4D space?

Comment: In this paper $\omega$'s are 2-forms in a Calabi-Yau manifold, which is (real) 6-dimensional, so $\omega_i\wedge\omega_j\wedge\omega_k$ is inevitably proportional to the volume form of the CY.

Comment: Of course, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\w}{\wedge}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$That integral vanishes because the differential form $\omega_i\w\omega_j\w\omega_k\in\Omega^6(S_4)$ vanishes (you cannot antisymmetrise more that $d$ indices in a $d$-dimensional manifold).

What you could do, instead, is use the fact that
$$\Omega^n(X\times Y)=\bigoplus_{p+q=n}\Omega^p(X)\w\Omega^q(Y),$$
to write
$$  \Omega^3\!\left(\R^{1,6}\times S_4\right) \ni C= \sum_{\begin{smallmatrix} 0\leq \!\!\!\!&p&\!\leq 3 \\ 0\leq \!\!\!\!&q&\!\!\leq 3\\ p+q&=&3\end{smallmatrix}} A_{[p]} \w \omega_{[q]}, $$
where $A_{[p]}\in\Omega^p\!\left(\R^{1,6}\right)$ and $\omega_{[q]}\in\Omega^q(S_4)$. Suppose that, for some reason, you only consider $\omega_{[q]}\in\mathrm{H}^q(S_4)$ (following e.g. [Compactification of D=11 supergravity on spaces of exceptional holonomy](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506150v2) that was linked in a comment by the OP).  Then the integral
$$\int_{\R^{1,6}\times S_4} C\w\d C\w \d C,$$
receives contributions from
$$ \omega_{[q]}\w \omega_{[q']}\w \omega_{[q'']}  $$
with $q+q'+q''=4$.

Let's expand $\omega_{[q]}$ in an orthonormal basis of the $q$-th cohomology group $\left\{\omega_{I_q}\right\}$, with $I_q\in \left\{1,2,\cdots, b_q=\mathrm{\dim}(\mathrm{H}^q(S_4))\right\}$:
$$ \omega_{[q]} = \left<\omega_{[q]},\omega^{I_q}\right>\ \omega_{I_q},$$ so that
$$C = \sum_{p+q=3} A^{I_q}\w \omega_{I_q},$$
with implicit summation over $I_q$ and with the coefficients $\left<\omega_{[q]},\omega^{I_q}\right>$ soaked up by $A^{I_q}$.

The desired integral decomposes, then, as
\begin{align} \int_{\R^{1,6}\times S_4} C\w\d C\w \d C &= \sum_{\begin{smallmatrix}p+q&=&3 \\p'+q'&=&3 \\ p''+q'' &=&3 \end{smallmatrix}}\int_{\R^{1,6}\times S_4} A^{I_q}\w \omega_{I_q} \w \d A^{J_{q'}}\w \omega_{J_{q'}}\w \d A^{K_{q''}}\w \omega_{K_{q''}} = \\ 
&= \sum_{\begin{smallmatrix}p+q&=&3 \\p'+q'&=&3 \\ p''+q'' &=&3 \\ q+q'+q''&=&4 \end{smallmatrix}} C_{I_{q},J_{q'},K_{q''}} \int_{\R^{1,6}} A^{I_{q}}\w\d A^{J_{q'}}\w\d A^{K_{q''}}, \end{align}
where
$$  C_{I_{q},J_{q'},K_{q''}} :=\int_{S_4} \omega_{I_q}\w \omega_{J_{q'}}\w \omega_{K_{q''}}, $$
generalise $C_{IJK}$ (eq. (3)) and $C_{IJk}$ (eq. (9)) of the linked reference. If, furthermore, in your case at hand some of the $C_{I_{q},J_{q'},K_{q''}}$ vanish you can simplify your result further.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks very much for the detailed answer!

Comment: Cheers! you can accept the answer by clicking the check button if you found it satisfactory :)

Comment: Just a note to the details of my question: I talked about the resolution of an $A_n$ singularity which I found out, by some result in algebraic geometry (which perhaps someone can fill in here since I don't know exactly myself), that only the zeroth and middle cohomology class of $S$ is non-vanishing (in this case $H^2$), and so in fact in the KK expansion of $C$ there are no other terms and so the Chern-Simons term vanishes.  Nevertheless, the answer is extremely useful for a general compactification. Thanks

Comment: But wait, it doesn't vanish. You can still use the zeroth cohomology. Then you have non-vanishing terms of the form $\omega_{I_2}\wedge\omega_{J_2}\wedge\omega_{K_0}$ (and permutations thereof).

Comment: Yes of course. I believe then that this term corresponds to the intersection form on $S$ which, again by the properties of $A_n$ (ADE/ Du Val) singularities, is equivalent to negative the Cartan matrix of the $A_n$ (ADE) group.